# Learning GCC ASM: SSE to NEON: Loads and Stores

Tags: gcc, assembly, sse, neon

I have a section of inline ASM code written using SSE instructions that I need to port to NEON. Rather than just have the whole thing converted in bulk I want to learn the basics myself and see if I can do it step-by-step.

So, the first step is learning loads and stores. Consider ...

```
float input[4] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f };
float output[4] = { 0 };
asm volatile
(
    "movups %[I], %%xmm0 \n\t"
    "movups %%xmm0, %[O] \n\t"
    : [O] "=m" (output[0])
    : [I] "m" (input[0])
    : "memory", "xmm0"
);
```

I know (I think) I'm supposed to use the vld1.32 instruction but I'm a little vague on combining that with some of the other GCC ASM constructs I've used before (like named variables, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
vld1.32 {d0,d1}, [%[I]]; 
vst1.32 {q0}, [%[O]];
```

depending on gcc version it recognizes q0 as d0,d1. 
Also I think you want to have (&output[0]) or simply (output) and (input) instead of loading the float to a general purpose register.

In ARM you can also post-increment the pointer: `xxx { }, [%[I]!]`

Consult e.g. [this](http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/241-coding-for-neon-part-3-matrix-multiplication/) for examples.

Comment: As it turns out, the constraints needed some tuning as well.
`"vld1.32 {d0,d1}, [%[I]] \n\t" "vst1.32 {d0,d1}, [%[O]] \n\t" : : [I] "r" (input), [O] "r" (output) : "memory", "d0", "d1"`

Comment: That's true. Also some gcc versions need both "d0", "d1" and "q0" in the clobber list.